# Alterar HTML durante requisição AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Olá, estou tentando mudar um texto na minha página web para acompanhar em tempo real algumas inserção no banco de dados, estou utilizando AJAX síncrono para fazer as requisições, mas o HTML não muda.

JavaScript:

```
result.forEach(function (value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: Config.path+"/admin/sensor/?machineId=" + machineId,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({name:value.name, collectType:value.collectType, nameAddress:value.nameAddress, ihmOperator:value.ihmOperator, dataType: value.dataType,
                                monitoring: value.monitoring, analytics: value.analytics, setpoint: value.setpoint, notification: value.notification,
                                class_type:value.class_type, range:value.range, charbehauvior:value.charbehauvior, observations:value.observations, showSensor:value.showSensor}),
        success : function(data, success, response){
            switch(response.status){
                case 200:
                    $('#sensorName').text(value.name);
                    console.log(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <p id="sensorName" style="text-align: left;" class="hidden"></p>
</div>
```

O "console.log(data)", logo abaixo do comando para mudar o HTML, funciona, imprime o que eu quero no console. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Então usa $('#sensorName').text(data), apenas tenha um cuidado por que geralmente o parâmetro "data" da callback success é um Array. Caso senha um array a sua variável data da callback entâo posta mais informações, pra poder te ajudar.

Comment: Mas se eu coloco console.log(value.name), ele printa no console o esperado, eu acho que esse problema tem alguma coisa tem a ver com o AJAX ser sincrono, pois ele imprime apenas o ultimo registro que está sendo inserido, mas eu preciso que seja sincrono.

Comment: A variável "data" quando da um console.log(data), tem os valores que você deseja ?
Você quer colocar apenas 1 valor na variável ou colocar todos os valores que vier da variável data na tela? tenta ser mais claro pra poder te ajudar.

Comment: Estou tentando apenas colocar o variável 'name' do data, que é a mesma coisa do 'value.name'. Quando eu dou o console.log(data) ele printa os valores corretos, e quando eu imprimo console.log(value.name) também. O 'data' e o 'value' são iguais.

Comment: Bota uma imagem do teu console.log(data) pra visulisar o que vem nele. Então você ta que rendo colocar todos os valores do Array data em uma string e mostrar na variável "sensorName" é isso ?

Comment: Não, dentro do array data, tem a variavel name, é ela que estou tentando colocar. O data.name. 
O value que eu coloco ali, é igual ao data, data = value e data.name = value.name

Comment: Acho que seu valor pode estar sendo sobrescrito afinal você está dentro de um forEach, e as respostas dadas deveriam ajudar, pode colocar uma foto do log ? ou alguma coisa do tipo pra ver se tem como ajudar .

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode usar o `append` no lugar do text, assim ele vai incluir no html que tenha o id desejado.

exemplo:

```
$('#sensorName').append('AQUI ENTRA O HTML QUE DESEJA');
```

Esse html pode ser uma `<label>COM_SEU_TEXTO</label>` ou qlq outra coisa, até uma `<div>` inteitra.

Comment: Não funcionou, deu o mesmo problema que comentei ali em cima, ele altera o texto apenas no ultimo elemento que foi inserido.

Comment: Estranho, pq o `append` não deveria alterar nada, apenas incluir, vc pode me monstrar como ficou a funcao com o `append` ?

Answer (score -1):

Tente tirar a class hidden

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <p id="sensorName" style="text-align: left;"></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Não é esse o problema, eu retiro essa class, quando eu aperto no botão para começar a inserção.
$('#sensorName').removeClass('hidden');

Comment: o campo esta em um modal?

Comment: Está em uma modal sim

Comment: tenta adicionar fora do modal para ver se vai dar certo, porque o código de alterar o texto esta certo, deve ter alguma coisa atrapalahando